# How To Get A Server Control Property Name With A Dash In It

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, custom-server-controls

I'm creating a custom server control in ASP.NET WebForms and want to have a hyphen in my property name the same way the ASP.NET server controls do in the markup. For example, a Label control has a "Font-Size" property in the markup like so:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" Font-Size="small" Text="hi" runat="server" />
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use complex properties on your control:

```
public class MyControl: WebControl
{
    public Test()
    {
        // Make sure to initialize the complex property or you will get a NRE
        // when you try to set the Complex-Bar property in the webpage
        Complex = new Complex();
    }

    public Complex Complex { get; set; }
}

public class Complex
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
<asp:MyControl runat="server" ID="myControl" Complex-Bar="foo bar" />
```

Comment: I tried this out and it's working. Do you know how to get intellisense to pop up using this approach?

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to get intellisense working with the complex property:

```
[Category("Appearance")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
```